# C - Why does this loop run through twice?

Tags: c, function, linked-list

This function is suppose to go back 1 step in the connect 4 game, however, it goes back twice... I went through the function with a debugger, and it seems to skip the getc() call I don't know why. Any help is much appreciated!

```
char UndoBoard(char x[ROWS][COLS], char * player){
    struct Node* temp = head;
    int i,j;
    temp = temp->next;
    char input = 'q';
    while((input != 'q' || input != 'Q') && temp != NULL){
        for (i=0;i<ROWS;i++){
            for (j=0;j<COLS;j++){
            x[i][j] = temp->data[i][j];
            }
        }
        printBoard(x);
        if(*player == 'O')*player = 'X';
        else *player = 'O';
        printf("b - undo one step more, f - go forward, q - resume game from here\n");
        input = getc(stdin);
        if(input == 'q' || input == 'Q')break;
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
}
```

Comment: In such a case where you need to run the loop at least once, it is better to use the `do {  } while (condition)` construct. In your case it will be `do { ... } while (input != 'q' && input != 'Q' && temp != NULL)`, or `do { ... } while (!(input =='q' || input =='Q' || temp == NULL))`.

Comment: @alvits: Not really, as `temp != NULL` is checked before and there has to be done something after the input is checked. Thus it should be `while ( temp != NULL ) ... `. The input code already results in a `break`.

Comment: @Olaf - that is true however I was referring to general constructs of when to use the `do {...} while (condition)` construct. But you are right, I missed the line in OPs code where it `breaks` when `input` is `q` or `Q`.

Comment: @alvits: You also missed the `temp = temp->next;`, which makes a `do .. while` loop useless :-)

Comment: Yes, since `input` is checked right after it is acquired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logic used in

```
while((input != 'q' || input != 'Q') && temp != NULL){
```

is faulty. You need to use:

```
while((input != 'q' && input != 'Q') && temp != NULL){
```

Comment: And when you fix that, the superfluous parentheses can be removed.

Comment: @BobbyJack Though, it's more of a personal thing for readability. If it helps the coder, then leave them in

Comment: Get used to misusing ```&&``` and ```||```. It happens more than people like to admit.

Comment: making this modification will result in the loop never executing unless input is initialized to something other than 'q'.

Comment: @MComp your condition `input != 'q' || input != 'Q'` is always `true`

Answer (score 4):

Your condition for `input` in the `while` condition is wrong. One of the two terms will be true, regardless of the value of `input`, so the loop only terminates here if `temp != NULL`.

But you actually `break` on user input later in the loop using a correct expression, so there is actually no need to test in the loop condition. Instead, use only `temp` here:

```
while ( temp != NULL ) {
```

Now you can also change

```
char input = 'q';
```

to

```
char input;
```

because it is now not before user input is read in the loop.

Note that `getc` returns an `int`, not a `char` to provide `EOF`, you also should test for. (thanks to @chux for pointing me at this).

As you just use it inside the loop, you can move it, to (all changes included):

```
while ( temp != NULL ) {
    int input;

    ...

    if ( input == EOF || input == 'q' || input == 'Q' )
        break;

    temp = temp->next;
}
```

Comment: Nice simplification.  Minor `int input; ... if ( input == 'q' || input == 'Q' || input == EOF)`